# Using Jersey 2.0 with JSP

Tags: jsp, rest, jersey, jax-rs

We load JSP pages in Jersey 1.x using `com.sun.jersey.api.view.Viewable`, for example:

```
@GET
public Viewable get() {
return new Viewable("/myPage.jsp", "");
}
```

What is the equivalent code for the above in Jersey 2.0?

Comment: jersey 2.0 is not under jsr311 but under jsr339 see: http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=339

Comment: Of course, but I cannot put jsr339 as a tag, it is not yet created at Stackoverflow as a tag:-)

Comment: I just created `jsr339` tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to http://java.net/projects/jersey/lists/dev/archive/2012-12/message/2 that feature is not yet ported to Jersey 2.0.

Comment: This answer looks out of date.

Comment: I guess that can be said about most of the answers in SO

Answer (score 2):

@Ankur thanks

```
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.mvc.Viewable;

@Path("/")
public class MyController {

    @GET
    @Produces("text/html")
    public Response index() {
        return Response.ok(new Viewable("/index.jsp")).build();
    }

}
```

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
   <artifactId>jersey-mvc-jsp</artifactId>
   <version>2.21</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Werner Vesterås mentioned, this isn't yet available in Jersey 2.0.

If you absolutely need this though, it might be possible to get a workaround going if you write a [`MessageBodyWriter`](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/snapshot/jersey/javax/ws/rs/ext/MessageBodyWriter.html) that forwards to a JSP. I think that's how the `Viewable` is handled in Jersey 1.x (with a [`ViewableMessageBodyWriter`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.sun.jersey/jersey-server/1.14/com/sun/jersey/server/impl/template/ViewableMessageBodyWriter.java?av=f) that resolves a [`JSPTemplateProcessor`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.sun.jersey/jersey-bundle/1.14/com/sun/jersey/server/impl/container/servlet/JSPTemplateProcessor.java#JSPTemplateProcessor)) or similar to what CXF's [`RequestDispatcherProvider`](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-redirection.html) is doing for JSP redirects.

Be aware though that [JAX-RS 2.0 spec is still a draft](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=339) and [Jersey 2.0 is still a milestone](http://jersey.java.net/jersey20.html) and as such subject to implementation changes. If you intend to use it in a production environment you should maybe reconsider and stick with Jersey 1.x instead.

Answer (score 1):

In Jersey 2.0, Use below to load jsp pages.
**<dependency>

          <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>

               <artifactId>jersey-mvc-jsp</artifactId>

              <version>${jersey2.version}</version>

</dependency>**

In your code, 
if model is sent to jsp, use like this :
**return new Viewable("/index.jsp", model);**

if no model is sent to jsp, use like this:
**return new Viewable("/index.jsp", null);**
                    OR
**return new Viewable("/index.jsp");**